# Lightning List Vew Search Not Returning Expected Results

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, list-view

I had finished migrating contacts from an old system to SalesForce, and upon having the data load checked, I got reports that the count of contacts was very low.

The users were using the search this list on the list view for the contacts.

When searching for 'Phoenix' (1), for example, only 7 records come back on the 'All Contacts' list view (2):
[image: List View Image]

When doing the search on the global search of contacts (1), I get 30 records (2):
[image: Global Search Image]

**EDIT**
I found the answer soon after I posted this - It only searches the 2000 records returned by the list view: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=basics_search_list_views_lex.htm&type=5

Comment: I only realized that you have edited your question to include this after I answered it, but you are right, that's the difference between the two searches here.

Comment: I feel that is my curse of SO - No matter how much time I spent searching before I ask, after I ask a question, I always find the answer online within an hour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between two searches are - [List View Search](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=basics_search_list_views_lex.htm&type=5) (available from Winter '19) vs. [Global Search](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=search_setup_parent.htm&type=5).

Global Search will attempt to search all those records in an Object to which the User has access to. Whereas List View Search only searches for records in that particular list view and is limited to only 2000 records.

> When you search a list view, only the first 2,000 records in the list view are searched.